# Slot load DVD burner options for standard desktop case

Tags: dvd, computer-building, burning, optical-drive

I need a new DVD burner (internal) for my father-in-law's computer. He's apparently broken the current one - he forgot to push the tray back in after doing something and hit it with his chair.

Given this, I'd like to get him a slot-loading DVD burner, so as to avoid the problem entirely. I need an internal device, and I'll be mounting in a 5 1/4" bay. He doesn't need any super-spec device - as long as it can read/write all the standard formats, it's good.

I see a few options at newegg.com, but they all have mixed reviews. Are there any out there that are generally seen as reliable?

How does one go about mounting slimline devices in a standard 5 1/4" bay? Is there a standard faceplate kit for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just finished spec'ing out a computer build that nearly required a slim optical drive.  Frankly, I'm not a fan of slot loaders at all, so there's not one I can particularly recommend.

But mounting a slim drive in a full-height 5.25" bay should be doable.  Not pretty, but doable.  I don't know of a mounting bracket offhand, which is what you'd really want, but I expect you'll be able to juryrig something if you can't find an existing product.

You'll need a slim SATA 7P-to-std adapter cable ([like this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812270183) -- this is an example, not a product recommendation) to hook up the final product.  The optical drive itself won't come with one (unless you're buying a retail version instead of an OEM drive).

**Update:**
Thanks to Molly's answer, I found the [Digistor](http://www.digistor.com/) company that provides [bezel kits](http://www.digistor.com/Products/Custom-Bezels_2) (including [single-slimline](http://www.digistor.com/Bezel-Kit-for-Single-Slimline-Blu-ray-DVD-Black-Bezel) and [dual-slimline](http://www.digistor.com/Combo-Kit-for-Dual-Slimline-Blu-ray-DVD-Drive-Black-Bezel) mounts) and a [5.25" SATA slot-loading drive](http://www.digistor.com/DIGISTOR-5-25-DVD-Writer-Slot-Load;jsessionid=0a0104451f4300825a187d764cec80018db36b1ae2f8.e3eSbNmQaheLe3iOa40) (available in DVD-RW and Blu-Ray varieties):

[image: dual-slimline drive mount]

[image: 5.25" SATA slot-loading drive]

Comment: ha! they've even got a combo bezel that'll fit a slimline 3.5" floppy drive under the upper slimline optical: http://www.digistor.com/Bezel-Combo-Kit-for-Slimline-Blu-ray-DVD-Floppy-Disk-Drive-Black

Comment: Presto! We have a winner! The Digistore drive is what I've just ordered for the job at hand. Thanks!

Comment: Post-install: This is working fine, but it turns out he's got a curved-front case. A tray-loading drive would normally push open the little spring-loaded door. For this install, I've removed the sprint-loaded door. Not ideal, but it's definitely not going to get broken again!

Comment: good deal!  i'm not surprised about the case's spring-loaded door.  glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the **[Plextor PX-DB608AL](http://www.shopmania.co.uk/shopping~online-cd-dvd-drives~buy-plextor-px-db608al~p-4369732.html)** dual bay slot-loading DVD writer:

[image]

Plextor also had a [full size slot-loader](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?Item=N82E16827131352), but it seems no longer available.

[image]

Comment: this one seems to be a 2007 vintage device; all the references i found online suggest it's sold with one EIDE drive (not SATA, tho you could certainly replace the EIDE or add your own SATA drive).

Comment: +1 just for posting the model and adding the link later... searching for the model is what led me to the product i listed in my answer.